# django-stdimage dynamic file structure

Tags: python, django, module

I am using django-stdimage in a django web app. I want to upload images using in a dynamic file structure according to when the image was uploaded. For instance:

```
snapshot/<year>/<month>/<filename>
```

Therefore, if I uploaded an image in May 2013, the image should be placed in this directory:

```
snapshot/2013/05/
```

My code looks like this in my models.py:

```
class Snapshot(BaseModel):
...
image = StdImageField(upload_to='snapshot/%Y/%m', blank=False, size=(1170, 780),   thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
...
```

In my template, I display the thumbnail like this:

```
<img src="{{snapshot.image.thumbnail.url}}">
```

We have since uploaded many images in the month of May. However, now that we have switched from May to June, all of the thumbnail paths are now pointing to June (current month) and not May (the month that we uploaded the images).

Does anyone know how I would fix this for future files uploaded and also files that were uploaded in the past?

Answer (score 1):

We met the same bug.

Cause of this bug: every time this StdImage instance init its .thumbnail field, it calls `self.generate_filename` to get its filename, then insert an '.thumnail' into filename as name of thumbnail.

Source:

```
def _set_thumbnail(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
    """Creates a "thumbnail" object as attribute of the ImageField instance
    Thumbnail attribute will be of the same class of original image, so
    "path", "url"... properties can be used

    """

    if getattr(instance, self.name):
        filename = self.generate_filename(instance,
                  os.path.basename(getattr(instance, self.name).path))

        thumbnail_filename = self._get_thumbnail_filename(filename)
        thumbnail_field = ThumbnailField(thumbnail_filename)
        setattr(getattr(instance, self.name), 'thumbnail', thumbnail_field)
```

It's right when the path is not dynamic. But when we use dynamic path such as `headimg = models.FileField(upload_to='headimg/%Y%m')`, return of `self.generate_filename` is corresponding to the date of today, so the thumbnail.path is changed every day.

**Quick Fix:**

In the source of stdimage/fields/py

```
def _set_thumbnail(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
    """Creates a "thumbnail" object as attribute of the ImageField instance
    Thumbnail attribute will be of the same class of original image, so
    "path", "url"... properties can be used

    """

    if getattr(instance, self.name):
        #fix the bug of wrong thumbnail path
        #filename = self.generate_filename(instance,
        #          os.path.basename(getattr(instance, self.name).path))
        file_path = getattr(instance, self.name).path
        file_prefix = self.upload_to[:self.upload_to.find('/')]
        filename = file_path[file_path.find(file_prefix):]

        thumbnail_filename = self._get_thumbnail_filename(filename)
        thumbnail_field = ThumbnailField(thumbnail_filename)
        setattr(getattr(instance, self.name), 'thumbnail', thumbnail_field)
```

It works for me.

I submitted an issue to the stdimage project on github. Hope the author will fixed it.